# Assigning default values to parameters when passed a NULL

Tags: c#

Is there a better way of doing this -

```
if (Number.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
{
    var status = _Logic.Order(data, Number);
} 
else
{
    var status = _Logic.Order(data);
}
```

Signature of the `Order` method -

```
Order(Data data, string number = "4a")
```

I am basically calling the same method in a different way based on if the `number` is NULL.

Comment: There is another way ;-) Create two `Order` overloads: `Order(Data data)` and , `Order(Data data, string number)`. Note that neither of these two overloads has an optional parameter. `Order(Data data)` should simply call Order(data, "4a") or perhaps preferably Order(data, null). Inside `Order(Data data, string number)` do the sanity checks for number like `if (string.IsNotNullOrEmpty(number)) number = "4a";` (which you currently seem to do outside of the Order method)

Comment: I usually do argument validation at the top of the method. Any reason you can't just do `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(number)) number = "4a";`?

Comment: Another way `Order(Data data, string number) { number = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number) ? "4a" : number }`

Comment: I'd just move the check for null to be inside of the order method itself. Keeps the calling code cleaner, especially if method called in multiple places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `null` is a valid value to be passed to a method, methods will typically have to deal with the possibility themselves that an argument may be null. Usually, you will see something like this then:

```
public void Example(string arg)
{
    if (arg == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arg));

    // …
}
```

That is for the case where passing a `null` value is not supported. But there is nothign wrong with explicitly allowing a `null` value to be passed and handling that internally. For example, instead of throwing an exception, you could simply assign a fallback value:

```
public void Example(string arg)
{
    if (arg == null)
        arg = "some default";

    // …
}
```

If you cannot modify your method to add such a logic, then you will have to deal with this outside. If you do know the fallback value yourself, then you can simply use one of these many ways:

```
// null-coalescing operator
_logic.Order(data, number ?? "4a");

// ternary conditional operator
_logic.Order(data, number != null ? number : "4a" );

// adjust the value separately first
if (number == null)
    number = "4a";
_logic.Order(data, number);
```

If you do not know the default value but instead have to rely on the default value that the method signature offers, or if you have to call a separate overload instead (where the second parameter is not used), then you will unfortunately have to use two separate calls for this. So you won’t be able to avoid this:

```
if (number != null)
    _logic.Order(data, number);
else
    _logic.Order(data);
```

---

Btw. of course, when dealing with strings, sometimes it makes more sense to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` instead of a strict null check. I’ve kept this a strict null check to show the general idea. You can of course adjust it as necessary.

Comment: I would go more for string.IsNullOrWhitespace as it does null, empty string, and whitespace only. A lot of people miss whitespace as an error catch.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey Depends a lot on your use case, but sure, use whatever makes most sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have control over the signature of `Order`, a simplified way to write your code from the caller's perspective would be to either use the `??` [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

```
var status = _Logic.Order(data, Number ?? "4a");
```

But that only checks for null, so if you want to check for empty as well, you can do:

```
var status = _Logic.Order(data, string.IsNullOrEmpty(Number) ? "4a" : Number);
```

But if you **do** have control over the method, then rather than have an optional parameter (which can cause some problems down the line if modified), another option is to provide different overloads for the method:

```
public static void Order (Data data)
{
    Order(data, "4a");
}

public static void Order (Data data, string number)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Of course this still doesn't prevent someone from passing `null` in the number field, so at some point you'll have to do some argument validation. This is pretty common in most methods:

```
public static void Order (Data data, string number)
{
    if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(number)) number = "4a";

    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I would make completely sure of documenting that behavior in the `number` parameter through XML comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to assign default values to parameters when passed NULL:

```
public static void Order (Data data, string number=null)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you can't refactor the `Logic` class for some reason, but you need to use its default, you could maybe use this pattern:

```
_Logic.Order(data, Number.IsNotNullOrEmpty ? Number : DefaultForNumber.Value);
```

But the implementation for `DefaultForNumber` is kind of a pain.

```
static Lazy<string> DefaultForNumber = new Lazy<string>
    (
        () => typeof(Logic).GetMethod("Order").GetParameters()[1].DefaultValue as string
    );
```

Comment: Wouldn't this pass `string.Empty` instead of `DefaultForNumber.Value`?

Comment: The pattern is sound; the condition is ambiguous (I don't know what `IsNotNullOrEmpty` is). Not really the point, which is to illustrate the way in which to retrieve the default value for a parameter.

Comment: Figured... Not my dv by the way